# How do we host AMP pages over Firebase hosting? | #AskFirebase

Tags: firebase, amp-html, firebase-hosting

1. Is it possible to create website using AMP pages that can be hosted over Firebase hosting..?
2. If yes, is that possible to create dynamic AMP pages that can add & fetch data to/from Firebase Firestore..?
3. If yes, please explain how is that possible..?

## AskFirebase

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. You can generate AMP compatible templates that are served over firebase hosting, or via an https triggered firebase function.

**Firebase functions hosting documentation:** https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

Your firebase function can dynamically fetch and serve data from Firestore / Realtime database. You can also implement caching so that static html is served from a CDN.

**Creating an AMP page from scratch:**
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/create/basic_markup

Just follow the AMP guide to ensure your code structure and syntax is correct.

Obviously this answer is very simple compared to implementation, but hopefully that gives you some direction and an idea of what is possible.

**Server Side Rendering Tutorial**
Google has a video series on server-side rendering with Firebase, I highly recommend it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbTn1czE2L8&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkbvTj8AUUCfBO7DoEHJ-ME

Comment: Thanks! Matthew Rideout - I found this answer useful.

Comment: How about signed exchange amp page?